# Is there a shortcut to make this edge selection?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, edges, shortcut, selection-tools

Is there a shortcut to do this type of selection quickly?

[image: Sides selected]

Here's another example with a cylinder:

[image: Sides selected cylinder]

I know I can do it by toggling xray and doing a square / lasso selection, but for some reason I remember being able to do this in the past just by clicking a modifier key like alt or something, similar to how you can select a loop by using alt in face select mode.

If there's a plugin that works too.

Thanks!

Comment: Select one, then go to the select menu > select loops > edge rings or CTRL +ALT + LMB

Comment: That's it! You select one edge. Then CTRL + ALT + LMB click on an adjacent edge and it will select the entire ring. So it turns out that I had an HDRI rotation plugin that was overriding that functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about any vanilla shortcut for such a thing, but you could try binding Select > Select Similar > Direction, or Length, to a hotkey to achieve a similar result.